# A Lipschitz limit of Riemannian metrics with curvature in $[-1,1]$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact manifold with a metric $g$ (not necessarily Riemannian one). Suppose that $(M,g)$ is a Lipschitz limit of a sequence of Riemannian manifolds $(M_n,g_n)$ with the sectional curvature bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

**Question.** Is it true that $(M,g)$ is an Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below by $-1$?

Comment: Lipschitz convergence implies Gromov-Hausdorff convergence, so the answer is yes.: $(M,g)$ is an Alexandrov space with curvature at least $-1$.  The upper curvature bound on $g_n$ is not needed for this conclusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot Igor! Do you think there is a reference that proves that the Gromov-Hausdorff limit of manifolds with curvature $\ge -1$ are Alexandrov spaces of curvature $-1$?

Comment: You meant to say "of curvature at least $-1$.  A reference is "A Course in Metric Geometry" by Burago, Burago, Ivanov, which is easy to find online.

Comment: Igor, I looked in the book but can't find the statement so far. If by any chance you remember where approximately it was written, could you please let me know?

Comment: In the book Example 7.4.3 states that Lipschitz implies GH, and Proposition 10.7.1 shows that lower curvature bounds are inherited by GH limits.